# Redirecting with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In my server root I have a directory called "repos".
I would like request like "server-name/repos/identifier" to call the "repos/index.php?id=identifier", where identifier is something the user can chose.

How do I accomplish this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put these rules in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?repos/(.*)$ /repos/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

or if you'd rather put rules in an htaccess file in the `/repos` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /repos/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That QSA made all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can place these rules inside the `.htaccess` file in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^repos/(.+) /repos/index.php?id=$1
```